# Is there a reliable way to read an in-circuit capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, meter, esr

Is there a reliable way to read an in-circuit capacitor?  I have a PCB-type ESR meter with a zero-force insertion socket that works for components, but do not have a meter that was designed to read specifically capacitors embedded in a circuit.

Comment: Can you measure how much flour went into a cake once it's baked?

Comment: This is unanswerable because it depends on the details of the circuit surrounding the capacitor and the measurement technique used.   And any coverage of the topic belongs at the existing question on this subject.

Comment: Thank you, That's exactly what I was looking  for, same situation.  I should have checked better if an answer already existed.